# ASP.NET MVC 5 model validation for non-nullable types (Int32)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-validation

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and the project owner is concerned about "under-posting" issues caused by validating non-nullable types (as mentioned in http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html and http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).

I created a test case to replicate this issue in ASP.NET MVC 5 but without luck.

Model:

```
public class ContactModel
{
    [Required]
    public Int32 data1 { get; set; }

    public Int32 data2 { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data1)
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data1)
    </div>
</div>  
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data2)
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data2)
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(Models.ContactModel contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Response.Write("modelstate is valid<br>");

        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("modelstate is invalid<br>");

        return View();
    }
}
```

It seems that when `data1` and `data2` are null in the post, their values in the model (`contact`) will be 0. However, ModelState.IsValid will also be **false** (instead of **true** as shown in the two articles).

What I have:

[image]

What the second article showed:

[image]

I couldn't find any information regarding changes on how model validation works in ASP.NET MVC, so I'm guessing I did something wrong with my test case. Any thought and suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: You do not need a `[Required]` attribute on an `int` property (unless you want a custom error message) - an `int` can never be `null`. The `DefaultModelBinder` adds an error because you cannot assign `null` to an `int` and sets `ModelState.IsValid = false`. But the value is `0` because that's the default value for `int`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's what I thought initially. But according to the post by Brad Wilson (the first link in my question): _The off-shoot of this is that [Required] on a non-nullable value type cannot act as a guarantee that the form included a value. If it doesn't include a value, then model binding is skipped, which means the model binding failure won't occur. Additionally, when the [Required] validator is run, it queries the value from the model -- which will contain the value-types default value, typically 0 -- and say "that's not null, everything is all good here!"._

Comment: That is wrong and model binding is never skipped. `ModelState.IsValid` will always be false if a value is sent for a property which is a value type or a reference type with a `[Required]` attribute

Comment: If you want validation on an integer type, the `[Required]` attribute is useless in this specific scenario. As the article also says: *Whether this is a problem depends on your scenario*. So if you want validation on an integer type, I suggest using the `[Range]` validation attribute, since it just makes more sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your ModelState is false is because the post is providing form values from each property in your model.  Essentially the Model binding system is checking the validity of both data1 and data2 fields as you have @Html.EditorFor helpers **explicitly** written for both properties in your view (so no underposting is actually going on).

I did successfully replicate the under-posting concerns from the articles.  Simply remove one of the EditorFor helpers in your view, so you're actually underposting.  With both helpers present, there's no underposting going on.  So the view looks like this now (note I added the validation helper for both properties to get feedback in the view on what's going on):

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data1)
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data2)
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to leave the @Html.EditorFor helper completely off for the data2 property.  Now fill in zero in the form field (you'll only one form field in the view of course now), and post to your action.

ModelState will come back as true in this scenario, even though only one form field is being posted.  Not a good result if someone does underpost!  So here's the (slightly modified) original model class where underposting issues will occur in the case a form field is left off of your form (note the Required attributes don't make any difference in this situation as both properties are value types):

```
//You could add the Required attribute or not, doesn't matter at this point.
//The concern here is that the Modelstate will still come back as Valid
//in the case of a form field being left off of your form (or someone underposts).
//So to replicate underposting issues, make sure to comment or delete
//at least one Html.EditorFor helper in the view.

//[Required] Underposting will occur regardless if this is marked required or not,
//so be careful if someone does underpost your form.
public Int32 data1 { get; set; }

//[Required]
public Int32 data2 { get; set; }
```

Now the solution if you want to solve the underposting issue:
Simply mark both properties as required and make them nullable as mentioned in the articles you provided, like so:

```
[Required]
public Int32? data1 { get; set; }

[Required]
public Int32? data2 { get; set; }
```

Now when the view is posted with a missing @Html.EditorFor helper or a missing form field, the ModelState Validation will come back as false, and you're protected from underposting issues.

Comment: Thanks! This does sound very promising. I will try to replicate this later today and mark for answer if it works.

Comment: Awesome Jim.  I ran it through the debugger and verified the behavior, so everything should work. Let me know if you have any questions on it.  By the way, I'm glad I came across your question.  That Required attribute can be misleading and all of a sudden you can get properties set to their default values if you're not careful.  Thanks, Tim