# ModelState.Isvalid invalidating field even though default value existed

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, required, modelstate

```
public abstract class Base : IBase
{
   [Required]
   public int key {get;set;}
}

public class Entity: Base
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class child : Entity
{
   [Required]
   public string Park {get;set;}
}
```

ActionFilter

```
public class ValidateViewModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false) {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when value is posted to API then, not setting "Key" field as it is the request for SAVE. Problem is, above attribute says, MODEL IS INVALID for field "key" . Its already there as 0 value for Id field (as default int).
I expect, it should validate true as 0 is default value.

NOTE: I could not remove or make any change in BASEENTITY and PARENT entity above.
I have only control in CHILD entity and this attribute class.

Comment: First, your editing data so do not use data models in your view - use view models. And a `int` is not nullable and required (your also have a `[Required]` attribute so if a `null` or invalid value is sent in the request then `ModelState` will be invalid (but the property will be initialized to its default)

Answer (score 1):

To ignore a property that is marked as `[Required]` you can use `ModelState.Remove("propertyName");`

Also, your property has a value of 0 because an `int` cannot have a value of `NULL` so the 0 is automatically attributed. But if you did not pass this value in the form data, the model validation will "consider" that it is `NULL` and thus will make the model invalid. If you do not want to use the call to `Remove` as shown above, you will have to explicitly give a value to the `Key` property :-)
source: [The first comment on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38071552/6838730) - credit for this explanation @Stephen Muecke

Use something like

```
public class ValidateViewModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ModelState.Remove("key");
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false) {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: By default, MVC6 model validation will simplicity tag all non-nullable value types as required (god knows why).
call

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved it by this way :

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Model.Server server)
        {
            if (server != null && ModelState.IsValid) //Invalid!!
            {
                _exchangeService.Create(server);
            }

            return Json(new[] { server }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

and replace model with viewModel ,because in viewModel we don`t have ID (refer to [Use ViewModel](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/view-model-asp-net-core-mvc/))

then we will have :

```
  [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ViewModel.ServerViewModel server)
        { 
            if (server != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _exchangeService.Create(server);
            }

            return Json(new[] { server }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```