# Validation occurs even Data Anotations is not set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I am working on dot net core 3.1. I have a form for submitting product details. I have used Data annotations with jQuery validations.

My problem is when I try to submit the form even the field which I haven't used data annotations is getting stops by validations. Even If I comment all data annotations in the modal also the validations is stopping me. I don't know what is causing problem. I have tried by cleaning and rebuild the solutions. But the problem remains.

I am getting below validation errors:

[image]

Below is the modal which I haven't added data annotations:

[image]

Below is cshtml:

[image]

Comment: I think it's because you didn't declare your fields as nullable... try adding e.g `public decimal? DiscountedProductPrice`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 5 model validation for non-nullable types (Int32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071552/asp-net-mvc-5-model-validation-for-non-nullable-types-int32)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that your model validation takes into consideration the datatype of the fields. So fields like `decimal` or `int` are non-nullable. But you can solve this by declaring your fields as `nullable`. For such types, you don't need to declare `[Required]` because by their very nature they cannot be null unless declared `nullable` using `?` operator.

Example:

`public decimal? DiscountedProductPrice`